# Unable to edit checkout flow settings

Tags: commerce

When attempting to configure Checkout Flow instances (eg, `/admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows/manage/default`) clicking on the 'Settings' (cog) icon for any of the panes generates an '*AssertionError*' and the settings cannot be altered.

```
AssertionError: The container was serialized. in assert() (line 28 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php)  
#0 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Container.php(28): assert(false, 'The container w...')
#1 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Container->__sleep()
#2 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/PhpSerialize.php(14): serialize(Array)
#3 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/KeyValueStore/DatabaseStorageExpirable.php(80): Drupal\Component\Serialization\PhpSerialize::encode(Array)
#4 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormCache.php(197): Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\DatabaseStorageExpirable->setWithExpire('form-GQXUq0kLih...', Array, 21600)
#5 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(459): Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache->setCache('form-GQXUq0kLih...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#6 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(437): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->setCache('form-GQXUq0kLih...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#7 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(629): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->rebuildForm('commerce_checko...', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Array)
#8 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(321): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('commerce_checko...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#9 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(91): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object(Drupal\commerce_checkout\Form\CheckoutFlowForm), Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#10 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch))
#11 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#13 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#14 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
#15 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#16 /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#17 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#18 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#19 /app/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#20 /app/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#21 /app/web/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#22 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#23 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#24 /app/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(708): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#26 /app/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#27 {main}
```

This behaviour is not seen on other Drupal forms across the site, including other pieces of Commerce, so the assumption is that the cause is the Checkout module.
Where similar errors have been reported elsewhere in Drupal, it's usually down to the Controller class not using  `DependencySerializationTrait`, but this seems to be implemented in */commerce/modules/checkout/src/Controller/CheckoutController.php*

The bad news is that I cannot replicate it: rolled another quick site using just Drupal 8.9.9 and Commerce 8.x-2.21 and the expected behaviour is working correctly.

### Proposed resolution

I've no idea what's causing this, and whether it is a config issue, or an issue with the code. As with every other Drupal site, there are lots of other modules, but it's knowing where to start...

Comment: Make a db backup and start disabling custom and contrib modules related to commerce that are not part/sub modules of the commerce module.

Comment: Also make sure the commerce module is up to date and there is nothing to update when you go to /update.php

Comment: Thanks - site was pretty much up to date. Biggest issue with disabling modules is that many Commerce-related ones can't be uninstalled - even if all order/cart data is deleted. Currently trying to uninstall Commerce Recurring, which is proving difficult

Comment: Very similar to [LogicException: The database connection is not serializable - when I try to open any “gear” on checkout flow page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297960/logicexception-the-database-connection-is-not-serializable-when-i-try-to-open) maybe one of the answers there will help you.

Comment: Do you have the Rules module installed? [could be from that](https://www.drupal.org/node/2803823). I also found [this other issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_form_element/issues/3155313) that is identical to yours on the same line 28.

Comment: Following through the threads you suggested, it seems that there is an unintended consequence from the mail_login module. As soon as it is disabled, then normal behaviour is restored to Commerce Checkout flow forms. See d.o issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_login/issues/3181217

While it's not a solution, it allows me to get back to site config and building for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to a problem with mail_login module.

Patch at https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_login/issues/3161437

Seems to be a recurring problem with modules that are missing DependencySerializationTrait